# If only one part of a macroscopic object interacts with the environment, does it affect the non-interacting part?

Tags: decoherence

In a state of quantum coherence, if only a part of a macroscopic object interacts with the environment, does the non-interacting part also have an effect?  Does the part that interacts with the environment affect the rest of the part that does not interact with it, so that behavior becomes classically unconditional?

Comment: Macroscopic objects *are* the environment.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin So in buckyball c⁶⁰, is c⁵⁹ the environment?  Even if it is isolated from the external environment, do c⁶⁰ constantly interact with each other, alternating between quantum decoherence and quantum coherence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since all parts of an object are (loosely speaking) constantly interacting with each other, so when one part of an object interacts with the environment, all parts of the object do.

If two parts of the object were not interacting, they would separate objects.

Comment: Then, assuming that the number of subatomic particles in a macroscopic object is about 10⁵⁰, if one photon and one subatomic particle interact and are measured, are all the remaining 10⁵⁰-1 subatomic particles measured?

Comment: To the best of our knowledge, an object consisting of $10^{50}$ particles cannot be in a quantum state in the typical sense of the word, i.e. a superposition of measurement outcomes. If one of the particles interacts with a photon, the particle cannot enter a quantum state since that would imply the whole object entering a quantum state. One way of understanding this is to say that the particle is measured by the $10^{50}-1$ particles, but that is not a very precise statement.

If this does not satisfy you, could you then clarify the "in a state of quantum coherence" part of your question?

Comment: So you're saying that for one particle in a macroscopic object, it's a 10⁵⁰-1 degree environment? And as soon as one particle interacts, the other 10⁵⁰-1 also changes from quantum to classical?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the object acts as an environment. It does not change from quantum to classical as an environment is always classical. In terms of decoherence the single particle interacting with the photon decoheres almost instantly.